# Loop through each table row to perform math operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below jquery add table

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
var html = '';
html += '<tbody><tr>';
html += '<td><select name="product_name[]" class="pu-input product_name"> 
<option value="">--Select--</option><?php echo 
fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="mt[]" class="pu-input mt" id="mt"/> 
</td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="ream[]" class="pu-input ream"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]" class="pu-input 
unit_price" id="price"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="d_price[]" class="pu-input d_price" 
id="discount"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="td_price[]" class="pu-input td_price" 
id="total_dis"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="vat[]" class="pu-input vat" id="vat"> 
</td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="t_vat[]" class="pu-input t_vat" 
id="t_vat"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="pu-input total" 
id="total"></td>';
html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
sm remove"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span></button></td></tr></tbody>';
$('#item_table').append(html);
$('tr').each(function(){
  $('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    var mt  = Number($('#mt').val());   // get value of field
    var price = Number($('#price').val()); // convert it to a float
    var discount = Number($('#discount').val());
    var vat = Number($('#vat').val());

    document.getElementById('total').value = mt * price;
    document.getElementById('total_dis').value = mt * discount;
    document.getElementById('t_vat').value = mt * vat;
   // add them and output it
  });
});
```

what I want to do is loop through each table row and perform a math function against two inputs, and populate the result into a third input.
but the problem is that the math functions are only working on the first row not working in the further rows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EehhL.jpg)

Comment: the math functions are not working on the next table row. but it is working on the first row. i have attached the image.

Comment: Can't have several elements with the same ID. That `$('tr').each(function(){ $('input').keyup(function(){ ...` code also does not make much sense, especially in what is already a handler. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Each time you add that html you are creating elements with duplicate ids.  You should reformulate your handler function to retrieve the elements you want to work with relative to the input that was typed in, rather than using IDs.

Comment: i am trying to have a real time calculation on the input fields also i want the calculation to be in each of the rows. can you tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: Not your immediate issue, but you shouldn't be creating `<tbody></tbody>` tags for each row, you should only have them once.  You also have a closing `</span>` tag that doesn't have a matching opening tag.

Comment: yeah fixed them thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, HTML element ids are meant to be unique. If you are not going to assign unique ids when you create the rows (say, with a counter that you increment each time), then you are better off just omitting the element ids.

Second, there is no need to create/assign event handlers each time you add a new row.  Instead, take advantage of delegated event handling. Remove your `$('tr').each(function(){` entirely and instead, outside of your row adding code, put this:

```
  $('table').on('keyup', 'input', function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    $thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();console.log($thisRow.find('td>.total'));
    var mt  = Number($thisRow.find('td>.mt').val());   // get value of field
    var price = Number($thisRow.find('td>.unit_price').val()); // convert it to a float
    var discount = Number($thisRow.find('td>.d_price').val());
    var vat = Number($thisRow.find('td>.vat').val());

    $thisRow.find('td>.total').val(mt * price);
    $thisRow.find('td>.td_price').val(mt * discount);
    $thisRow.find('td>.t_vat').val(mt * vat);
   // add them and output it
  });
```

This code will traverse the DOM (admittedly probably not the most efficient thing to do) relative to the input that is currently handling the keyup event, and put values into the appropriate target inputs based on their relative locations.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5cxoghb2/)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Glad to help.  The answer from James is probably worth a look (and upvote) too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit obfuscated, try to format it nice next time. This will help you read it faster and will make it more maintainable.

However here is a basic example of how to achieve this:

```js
function calculate () {
  const val1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  const val2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  
  document.getElementById('output').value = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
}

$('#calculate').on('click', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="number">
<input id="input2" type="number">
  <br>
  <br>
<button id="calculate">calculate</button>
  <br>
  <br>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
Output <input id="output" type="number">
```

Comment: This doesn't really address OP's issue of multiple rows of inputs

Answer (score 0):

Once you sort out the click handler, the only real issue you have is the use of relative positioning instead of ids to locate items within the row in question.  Here's your code reformatted with comments explaining the changes

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><select name="product_name[]" class="pu-input product_name"> 
<option value="">--Select--</option><?php echo 
fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="mt[]" class="pu-input mt"/> 
</td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="ream[]" class="pu-input ream"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]" class="pu-input 
unit_price"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="d_price[]" class="pu-input d_price"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="td_price[]" class="pu-input td_price"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="vat[]" class="pu-input vat"> 
</td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="t_vat[]" class="pu-input t_vat"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="pu-input total"></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
sm remove"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
});
// end of add.click handler

// since #item_table exists but its rows might not yet, use a delegated event handler attached to #item_table
$('#item_table').on("keyup", "input", function() { // run anytime any value changes
  // locate parent row relative to the input that was typed in
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  // locate mt and so on within the row by class - don't need id
  var mt = Number(row.find('.mt').val()); 
  var price = Number(row.find('.price').val());
  var discount = Number(row.find('.discount').val());
  var vat = Number(row.find('.vat').val());

  // output, again find the fields by class
  row.find('.total').val(mt * price);
  row.find('.d_price').val(mt * discount);
  // etc

  });
});
```